# jQuery alert beyond certain scroll height

Tags: jquery

I am trying to run a function at a certain scroll point, im testing it with an alert first, but cant get the alert to fire when the scroll point goes past a certain point

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {

    var windowScroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop(); 

    if (windowScroll > 160) {
        alert("windowScroll");
    }
});
```

Have i missed something obvious? Thanks.

Comment: Try to use `jQuery(document).scrollTop();` instead of `jQuery(window).scrollTop();`. But your code should be working imo. When this script is executed ? Execute it in a `$( document ).ready` handler.

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/8Bb6m/, but for this kind of checks is better to use console.log

Comment: must have some jQuery clash going on somewhere then because i thought i should work, and when i put it in a stand alone file it works fine, thats frustrating!! Thanks guys.